# How do I disable dynamic prerendering for all pages while building a NextJS 13 app?

Tags: next.js, next.js13

Self explanatory title.
I'm trying to build a next application in a docker container that interacts with a volume mount. Since the volume mount path is not available while the docker image is being built, the next app isn't also being built at the same time.

What changes should I make to stop next from pre rendering dynamic pages and/or all pages while the app is being built?
I'm using app router (and not page router).

Any changes would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

I'm not sure what changes to be made to fix this.